# Deallocate dynamic memory

Tags: c++

I have written some code like this:

```
        double *psi1 = multiplyscalar(
                            multiplyscalar(submatrix( multiplyscalar(I3, ttt2, 3, 3), multiplyscalar(multiply(teta0, teta0t, 3, 1, 1, 3), pow(*ttt, -1.5), 3, 3),3,3), 2, 3, 3)
                            ,(  (*multiply(A3t, mu, 1, m, m, 1))-( *multiply(multiply(multiply(transpose(mu, m, 1), G1, 1, m, m, m),transpose(G, m, m), 1, m, m, m), mu, 1,m,m,1) ) )
                            ,3
                            ,3
                   );
```

Where the functions called are similar to this:

```
static double* multiply(double A[], double B[], int ra, int ca, int rb, int cb){
if(ca != rb){
    hal.console->printf("\n multiplication error\n");
    return nullptr;
}
double* C = new double[ra*cb];
double sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < ra; ++i){
    for(int j=0; j<cb; j++){
        for(int x=0; x<ca; x++){
            sum += A[(i*ca)+x]*B[(x*cb)+j];
        }
        C[(i*cb)+j] = sum;
        sum = 0;
    }
}
return C;}
```

So I have memory leak because those pointers that are returned are never "erased".

Is there a way to `delete` them afterward?
I know doing every operation separately would bypass the issue, but I was searching for a more elegant solution?

Comment: Ditch "arrays" and use `std::vector`

Comment: In any other way you're caught and urged to use `new[]` (e.g. by a sadistic and incompetent teacher) ,call `delete[]` after you don't need that array anymore.

Comment: @user0042 Yeah, my problem is how do i call `delete` on those pointers? I don't have any direct reference to them

Comment: use smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr`, it will take care of memory deallocation for you.

Comment: @user2833876 - It's rather easy. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46524938/deallocate-dynamic-memory#comment80003642_46524938).

Comment: @user2833876 _"I don't have any direct reference to them"_ What do you mean? Don't you save the result in a pointer variable when you call that function?

Comment: @user0042 no, that's the problem. I said in the question that by doing each call separately that would be easy, but in this case the pointers created are used by the other functions and then I lose track of it.

Comment: @user2833876 Then either keeping track, or using `std::unique_ptr` or using a `std::vector` is certainly the correct solution to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return a proper container, e.g. some [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (or your `class` using it). Read also about the [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Maybe define a `template` function (with the template arguments being the sizes, perhaps using `std::array`).

Consider also smart pointers (like [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)), avoiding explicit `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a class wrapper around your array and delete the pointers in the destructor. Not the most elegant way, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than nest function calls 5(!) deep, leaking allocations all the way, you can split sub-expressions out into variable assignments.

Then ditch `double[]` and use [`std::vector<double>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which will handle all the allocations for you.

Then throw away all your hand-written functions and use a robust [Linear](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) [Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK) [Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.html), which will probably expose some functions as `operator+` and `operator*` et. al, and lazily evaluate the result.